# How can I extract a page range from a PDF file AND retain the PDF tagging in the new file

Tags: pdf

I've found and tried several of the solutions to extracting a page range from a PDF file (pdftk, Ghostscript, etc.). They all work, but they all seem to strip the tagging (PDF tags, used to make documents more accessible) from the resulting file.

Does anyone know of a solution, or a set of options I can use with an existing solution, to extract a page range AND **retain the PDF tags** in the extracted file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To preserve original tags in the extracted pages range, please use an application that supports tag extraction. One open source and excellent application is **[PDFSAM](https://pdfsam.org/)**.

1. Install it by running the following command in the terminal:

`sudo apt install pdfsam`

2. Open your file with PDFSAM and choose **Extract**. Then, specify **pages range** separated by commas, chose your **output directory**, and click **Run** like in the image bellow:

[image]

**Done:** Your extracted pages range with tags preserved will be located in the chosen output directory.

Comment: Thanks for this. I was actually looking for a command-line tool not a graphical one, apologies for not making that clear. I found a link via the pdfsam site to the sejda SDK which seemed to offer that, but unfortunately upon testing I discover that tags are not preserved when extracting pages using that tool.