# Is there anything to read and hand-annotate a pdf like on paper on a touchscreen with stylus?

Tags: pdf, touchscreen, multi-touch

I have a DELL touchscreen convertible and I would like to be able to read, but also annotate with a stylo like I am used on paper, a pdf, so to say bye bye to paper.

I can't find any PDF reader however that fulfil my needs.
Ideally the reader would:

- have just a few buttons to manage settings (colour, width, erase..) of the pensil and leave the rest of the area for the pdf content
- once the pencil is selected stay with it (no okular), no need to select it again and again for any "line"
- have a dark mode as Evince
- (optional) keep the file format as an annotated PDF
- have some basic touch gestures like switching page, zoom, exit full screen
- when the pencil is recognised, disable the touch with the hand (if I write on the screen with the pencil, I don't want that the side of my hand makes lots of other sign on the screen)

I have tried Xournal, Scribus, pdfstudioviewer, Okular and a few more, but none is really usable for the task  I am looking for.
I never had a dedicated book reader, but maybe that is instead the solution to go ? What do you think ?

Comment: [PDFSAM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1171283/how-can-i-extract-a-page-range-from-a-pdf-file-and-retain-the-pdf-tagging-in-the/1171300#1171300) is worth checking. It offers [annotation](https://pdfsam.org/pdfsam-enhanced/#comment-pdf) in the **premium edition**. I have only  tried the basic edition and not the premium though.

Comment: @raffa I am not sure it is pertinent, seems more a PDF toolkit..

Comment: **Xournal++** offers extra customization that is not available in **Xournal**. I explained in the answer below. I hope you find it useful.

Answer (score 8):

**Xournal++** is a feature-rich hand note-taking software:

> **Xournal++** is an cross-platform, open source, hand note-taking software
> with the target of flexibility, functionality, and speed. It is a
> modern rewrite and more feature-rich version of the wonderful [Xournal](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xournal/)
> program.
>
> **Features:**
>
> - Pressure-sensitive styluses and digital pen tablets (e.g. Wacom, Huion, XP Pen, etc. tablets).
> - Plugins support via the [Lua programming language](https://lua.org/).
> - Customizeable toolbar, with multiple configurations, e.g. to optimize toolbar for portrait / landscape.
> - "Paper" backgrounds for notetaking, scratch paper, or whiteboarding.
> - Different pen types (e.g. eraser, highlighter) and stroke styles (e.g. solid, dotted).
> - Different shapes, such as lines, arrow, circle, rectangle, splines.
> - Shape resizing and rotation.
> - LaTeX support (requires a working LaTeX install).
> - Multiple "layers" for easier control over overlapping notes and strokes.
> - Sidebar with page previews and PDF Bookmarks.
> - Audio recording and playback alongside with handwritten notes.
> - Rotation and grid snapping.
> - Annotate on top of PDFs.
> - Export to a variety of formats including SVG, PNG, and PDF.
> - Multi language support (over 20 languages supported, with more added by the community!).
>
> More info: https://xournalpp.github.io/

---

**[Xournal++](https://snapcraft.io/install/xournalpp/ubuntu)** is also available from the snap store. You can install it like so:

```
sudo snap install xournalpp
```

It allows you to customize **toolbars** from the **view** menu so you can have a simple interface like this in the **full screen** mode:

[image]

Or even simpler custom interface by dragging and dropping adding / removing tools like so:

[image]

So that you only have the tools you need like so:

[image]

Comment: The best answer! Thank you, PDF annotations are saved as expected and I can share files, all changes are visible. Thank you.

Comment: Just discovered xournal++ based on the recommendation. It is indeed a very complete PDF annotation program. Much better than Okular that I was using earlier. Thank you for the recommendation.