# Okular text annotation does not appear

Tags: pdf, okular

I decided to give `okular` a try for editing pdf files but I am having an issue with the 'typewriter tool'.

The text I type does not appear on the pdf itself within the okular editor. If I save the file and open it with another program it appears normally though:

[image]

Changing the font type, size and color didn't change anything. I also can't find anyone else who's ever had this problem so I'm at a bit of a loss here.

Comment: Alternative: https://askubuntu.com/a/1314422/968501